# Stack unsupported version

Tags: haskell, archlinux, haskell-stack, stackage

I'm trying to build [libssh2-hs](https://github.com/portnov/libssh2-hs) with stack (lts-3.20) and I get some errors:

```
$ stack build
No compiler found, expected minor version match with ghc-7.10.2 (x86_64-ncurses6) (based on resolver setting in /home/black/programmation/haskell/libssh2-hs/stack.yaml).
To install the correct GHC into /home/black/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/, try running "stack setup" or use the "--install-ghc" flag.
$ stack setup
No information found for ghc-7.10.2.
Supported versions for OS key 'linux64-ncurses6': GhcVersion 7.10.3, GhcVersion 8.0.1, GhcVersion 8.0.2
```

I use archlinux 64 bits, what happens here and what can I do?

Comment: Update LTS version?

Comment: That'd imply a package modification and it seems against the stack's mindset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem is hinted at by this error message:

> ```
> No information found for ghc-7.10.2.
>   Supported versions for OS key 'linux64-ncurses6': GhcVersion 7.10.3, GhcVersion 8.0.1, GhcVersion 8.0.2
> ```

Arch Linux provides by default libncurses6, while the standard builds of GHC expect libncurses5/libtinfo5. Stack can fetch alternative GHC builds that use libncurses6; however, they are only available from GHC 7.10.3 onward, which explains why you are having this issue with a snapshot that uses GHC 7.10.2. The following suggestion, taken from [Stack issue #3177](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3177), should solve it:

> Install [ncurses5-compat-libs](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/) from AUR and then force Stack to use the standard GHC bindist by doing something like `stack --ghc-build=standard setup`.

(Note that the `--ghc-build=standard` might not be necessary -- if I remember correctly, when I ran into this issue several months ago `stack setup` detected the appropriate GHC build once I installed ncurses5-compat-libs, with no need to specify it explicitly.)